# Can't display Backbone/Underscore template in Jade view

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, pug

I'm trying to link the template in my .jade view to my Backbone model, and it's just not displaying anything inside my template script.

**My .jade view:**

```
extends ../layout
block content
  .page
    script(type="text/template" id="createRecipeTemplate").
      <div class="ingredients-pane">
        <form id="ingredientForm">
          *[form]*
        </form>
        *[etc.]*
      </div>

  script(src='/js/myBackboneFile.js')
```

**myBackboneFile.js:**

```
var Recipe = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {*[defaults]*}
});

var Recipes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/api/recipes'
})

var recipes = new Recipes();

var RecipeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: new Recipe(),
    el: '.page',
    initialize: function() {
        this.template = _.template($('#createRecipeTemplate').html());
    },
    events: {
        *[events]*
    },

    *[functions for my events]*,

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

var RecipeView = new RecipeView();
```

Everything's linked up - if I type 'RecipeView' into the browser console, it gives me:

```
n {cid: "view2", $el: n.fn.init[1], el: div.page}
```

I've tried a few variations on the jade template syntax - putting pipes at the beginning of each line, using the dot after the script tag (as above), and just indenting normally (with the template in both standard HTML and Jade syntax each time), but no joy.

Am I missing something obvious?